# AppxProvisionedPackage commands stuck on PowerShell and return DismInitialize failed

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, uwp, lob

I am trying to install LOB UWP application
I used:

> Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath "APPX_PATH"
>   -DependencyPackagePath "DEPENDENCIES"-SkipLicense

It worked for the first time, i even asked one of my colleagues to log in and the app was there.
But, after that, i tried to reinstall it with the same command. But the command refused to execute, it's just blinking and loading.

I tried other commands to get the packages or remove the package but all have the same behavior.
What could be a valid reason for that?

> Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online | Select PackageName
>
> Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
>         -PackageName "PackageName" -Online -AllUsers

EDIT#1:I am getting the following error after waiting for long time and pressing PgDn or End buttons on keyboard.

```
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage : DismInitialize failed. Error code = 0x80004005
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -PackageName PACKAGE_NAME ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.RemoveAppxProvisionedPackageCommand
```

Comment: Why are you using Add-AppxProvisionedPackage instead of Add-AppxPackage which mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10).

Comment: Add-AppxPackage is used to install the UWP on the current user only. Add-AppxProvisionedPackage will install the app in current users and future users. This is not the issue though as i need to know why the later worked once only.

Comment: Are you trying to install the app into a Windows image?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, yes, i am trying to install the app for all current users and future users.